# ggarrange not plotting every ggplot object

Tags: ggpubr

I am trying plot `8` `ggplot` objects with `ggarrange` such that it plots `4` ggplot objects in each row, so the plot grid has `two` rows (`nrow = 2`). But the code below does not return the plot correctly as seen below. How can this be fixed? On a side note when I plot with `nrow = 1`, all 8 plots show correctly.

```
gg.arrange = ggarrange(ggplot1,
                                  ggplot2,
                                  ggplot3,
                                  ggplot4,
                                  ggplot5,
                                  ggplot6,
                                  ggplot7,
                                  ggplot8,
                                  nrow = 2,
                                  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
                                  common.legend = TRUE,
                                  legend = "bottom")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you add `ncol = 4` to your code?

Comment: So by adding ncol = 4 and nrow = 2 to the code does the trick. Cheers for the tip. Should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ggarrange()**

`ggarrange()` apparently requires both `nrow` and `ncol`, so Add `ncol = 4` to your code.